# Converting Object Names to Strings in AS2

Tags: string, object, for-loop, actionscript-2, movieclip

So i've made an object called "potato", then started a loop to check if something in "_level0" has the name of "_level0.potato". What i think is that since the the things in _level0 are objects instead of strings, the object name can't be recognized as a string, so im guessing i need to find a way to convert the object name to a string or vice versa.

```
var potato:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("potato", this.getNextHighestDepth());
for(objects in _level0){
trace(_level0[objects])
    if(_root[objects] == "_level0.potato"){
        trace("OMG, i found a potato on level0")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion that the objects are stored as a string is incorrect. If you try using `typeof` before your

```
trace(typeof _level0[objects])
```

you will see that its type is `movieclip`
and your "_level0.potato" is `string`
They will not be equal. But you can convert object reference to string using `String(...)` construct.

And about names. You're confusing names and references. MovieClip object like some others in ac2 have property called `_name`. In this property name of object is stored like string. But only name, not the full path to its destination.
For your potato mc `_name` will be equal `"potato"`
So you could do your search like this

```
var potato:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("potato",this.getNextHighestDepth());
for(objects in _level0){
trace(_level0[objects])
    if(_root[objects]._name == "potato"){
        trace("OMG, i found a potato on level0")
    }
}
```